# Is it ok to store a json in a row on a table of a relational database or should I do a one to many relation instead?

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to store my data. I'm basically trying to keep track of a scoring progress in a match. This is my model (c#)

```
public class Match{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int Participant1 {get;set;}
  public int Score1 {get;set;}
  public int Participant2 {get;set;}
  public int Score2 {get;set;}
}
```

I want to model this so that I can track when a participant scores so I can make a graph out of it. I feel like I can just put in a string field (property) and add a json like so:

```
[{ score1: 2, score2 : 0, time: '4:30'},
{ score1: 0, score2 : 2, time: '3:28'},
{ score1: 0, score2 : 2, time: '2:30'},
{ score1: 0, score2 : 2, time: '1:50'},
{ score1: 4, score2 : 0, time: '1:30'},
{ score1: 2, score2 : 0, time: '0:30'},]
```

With that said, is it ok to do this or is it better to have a one to many relationship and just create another object that connects to the Match?

eg

```
 public class Match{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int Participant1 {get;set;}
  public int Score1 {get;set;}
  public int Participant2 {get;set;}
  public int Score2 {get;set;}

  public virtual ICollection<MatchScore> MatchScores {get;set;};
}

public class MatchScore{
   public int MatchId {get;set;}
   public int Score1 {get;set;}
   public int Score2 {get;set;}
   public string Time {get;set;}

   public virtual Match Match {get;set;};
}
```

Comment: Serializing a JSON object to a CLOB is common.  You're using a relational database to store a document.   I think it's fine.  Just think about adding additional columns if there are values inside the document that you need to query for it efficiently.

Comment: I second what @duffymo says: if you just want to store something, it's perfectly fine to keep the json as it is. If you want to query the data, either use one of the json types (like jsonb) or transform it into a relational structure.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to have 2 tables:

1. You don't need to take care how to parse json. Later you can have problem when you will add new feature.
2. You will have problem when querying database(ex.: how much goals was after 15 minutes of match)
3. Also you will have data integrity